# When making GET request, getting "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

I m making GET request to Backend, with the token, but getting this error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:8067/v1/api/subscriber/list/1/20' from origin 

'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request 

doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

**I have seen the solutions here but None of them worked me. Could you assist me with this issue?**

Is this Frontend or Backend issue?

code:

```
export const getAllSubscribers = async (page, limit) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token').split(":")[1];
  
    const url = api.allSubscribers(page, limit);

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');


    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
      });

      console.log("response------->", response.headers);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error fetching subscribers: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
  
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occurred during allSubscribers request:", error);
      throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your server-side logic set up correctly to handle the OPTIONS request, and give a 200 OK response ...?

Comment: Assuming you've already added CORS headers to the response, then the problem is because the preflight request isn't returning a 200 OK response. You need to debug what response it is returning and fix it

Answer (score 1):

Preflight request an HTTP request of the OPTIONS method, sent before the request itself, in order to determine if it is safe to send it and this request is blocked  due to CORS policy occurred when you tried to request to http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:8067/ from http://localhost:5173.

If you are using Node.js + Express Backend, I recommend to configure CORS in the backend.

```
const whitelist = ['http://localhost:5173']

app.use(cors(
  {
    origin:whitelist,
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "PATCH"],
    credentials:true,
    exposedHeaders: ["Set-Cookie"]
  }
  )
)
```

Also, you need to configure Fetch headers to accept credentials in Frontend as well.

```
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        credentials: true // Add this line.
      });
```

Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is this Frontend or Backend issue?

It's a backend issue. Your server isn't responding to the `OPTIONS` preflight HTTP call with a response with a success code, so the cross-origin call is disallowed. You probably just have the server responding to `GET`, but certain `GET` calls (and all `POST` and similar calls) trigger an `OPTIONS` call before the `GET`, a so-called "preflight" call, and your server is apparently not handling that (so it's returning a `404` or `405` or similar instead, instead of a `200` or similar containing a response with the necessary resource-sharing headers).

More:

- [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)
- [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS)